# Load user data at login - react native

Tags: react-native

I have an application where I can log in and if the username and password are correct it sends me to my screen, but I need it to load the data of the user who logged in and I can't do it, "undefined" always appears.

For this login I have an AuthContext.tsx where I have a constant "signIn" where it is verified that the username and password are correct and it sends me to my screen in addition to creating the token without problems, but I also have another constant called "checkToken" which is supposed to check the token and get me the user data from the API to use later, but it doesn't.

The API that I use is in .php and it works correctly since I use it with a react.js project and it works fine but in react-native I have not been able to load the two user data when logging in.

Code Api y project:  https://github.com/Giovannychvz/login

AutContext.tsx

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

    import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
    import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
    import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

    type AuthContextProps = {
        errorMessage: string;
        token: string | null;
        user: Usuarios | null;
        status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
        signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
        signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
        logOut: () => void;
        removeError: () => void;

    }

   const authInicialState: AuthState = {
        status:'checking',
        token: null,
        user: null,
        errorMessage:''
    }

    export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);
    export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

        const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

        useEffect(() =>{
            checkToken();
        }, [])

        const checkToken = async () =>{
           const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

           //No token, no autenticado
           if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
        
           //hay token
           const resp = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');

           if(resp.status !== 200){
              return dispatch({type:'notAuthenticated'});
           }

           await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resp.data.token)       

           dispatch({
               type: 'signUp',
               payload:{
                   token: resp.data.token,
                   user: resp.data.usuarios
               }
           })

        }

       const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
           
            try {

         await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php',
        {
          method:'POST',
          headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'content-Type': 'application/json'
     
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(resData => {
           if(resData.message == "Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.") {    

            dispatch({
                type: 'signUp',
                payload: {
                    //el token carga sin problemas
                    token: resData.token,
                    user: resData.usuarios
                }
                
            }); 
                    
           }else{
            Alert.alert(resData.message)
           }
           
        });
               }catch (error) {
                dispatch({type: 'addError',
                payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
               }
        };

        

        return(
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{
                ...state,           
                signIn,        
                removeError,
            }}>
               {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )

    }
```

cafeApi.tsx

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const baseURL = 'https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero';

const cafeApi = axios.create({baseURL});

cafeApi.interceptors.request.use(

   async(config) =>{
     const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
     if (token){
         config.headers['x-token'] = token;

     }
     return config;
   } 
);

export default cafeApi;
```

Screen.tsx

```js
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Button, Image, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'


interface Props extends StackScreenProps<any, any>{}

export const ProtectedScreen = ({navigation}: Props) => {

  const {user, token} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
        <View>
             
          <Text>
         //AQUI DEBERIA CARGAR LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO PERO NO CARGA NADA
                {JSON.stringify( user, null, 5) }
            </Text>
  </View>

    

    </>
  )
}
```

I found a halfway solution, when I start the session it loads the user's profile data but other times it doesn't, it must have some detail that is generating the conflict.

In fact, what I did was modify my "checkToken", in case someone can help me, I almost have it.

AuthContext.tsx

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    checkToken: () => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:''


}


export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);
export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const [theUser, setUser] = useState(null);
    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);

    
    
   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
      
        try {
          const res = await fetch('https://portal.tuparcero.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email: correo, password: password }),
          });
          const resData = await res.json();
      
          if (resData.message == 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.') {
            // Guardar el token en AsyncStorage
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);
          console.log(JSON.stringify({theUser}) + "PERFIL");
            dispatch({
              type: 'signUp',
              payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios,
              },
            });
          } else {
            Alert.alert(resData.message);
          }
          //console.log(resData)
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response?.data?.msg || 'Información incorrecta',
          });
        }
      };

  

    const checkToken = async () =>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 
        cafeApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
        
        if(token){
         const {data} = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');
         if(data.success && data.user){
             setUser(data.user);
             //console.log(JSON.stringify({theUser}) + "aquifue");
             return;
         }
         setUser(null);
     }
       
        //No token, no autenticado
        if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
    
     }
 
 
     useEffect(() => {
         async function asyncCall(){
             await checkToken();
         }
         asyncCall();
     },[]);
     

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signIn,
            removeError,
           // user:theUser,
            checkToken,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

running
[image]

without working

[image]

Comment: I found a halfway solution, when I log in it loads the user's profile data but other times it doesn't, it must have some detail that is generating the conflict.

In fact, what I did was modify my "checkToken", in case someone can help me, I almost have it.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue of the profiles of each user, add the `signIn` function to the `useEffect` of the `checktoken` and when loading the js it was not enough to load the user information and that is why it always appeared null now every time the session is loaded the data and calls the `checktoken` function passing it the information:

```js
import React,{ createContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

import cafeApi from "../api/cafeApi";
import { LoginData, LoginResponse, RegisterData, Usuarios } from "../interfaces/appinterfaces";
import { authReducer, AuthState } from "./AuthReducer";

type AuthContextProps = {
    errorMessage: string;
    token: string | null;
    user: Usuarios | null;
    status: 'checking' | 'authenticated' | 'not-authenticated';
    signUp: (RegisterData: RegisterData) => void;
    signIn: (loginData : LoginData) => void;
    checkToken: () => void;
    logOut: () => void;
    removeError: () => void;

}

const authInicialState: AuthState = {
    status:'checking',
    token: null,
    user: null,
    errorMessage:''


}

export const AuthContext = createContext({} as AuthContextProps);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: any) =>{

    const [theUser, setUser] = useState(null);

    const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer,authInicialState);   
  
   const signIn = async({correo, password}: LoginData) => {
       
       try {
        const res = await fetch('https://webcom.com/apiTuparcero/usuarios/login.php', {
         // const res = await fetch('https://alira.ai-od.com/apiAlira/usuarios/login.php', {
         
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
         
           body: JSON.stringify({ email: correo, password: password }),
          });
          const resData = await res.json();
      
          if (resData.message == 'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.') {
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', resData.token);
                  dispatch({
              type: 'signUp',
              payload: {
                token: resData.token,
                user: resData.usuarios,
              },
            });
          } else {
            Alert.alert(resData.message);
          }
          //console.log(resData)
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response?.data?.msg || 'Información incorrecta',
          });
        }
      };

     const checkToken = async () =>{
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
 
        cafeApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
        
        if(token){
        const {data} = await cafeApi.get('/usuarios/user-info.php');
               if(data.success && data.user){
             setUser(data.user);
           console.log(data.user.name + " base de datos_check");
             return;
         }
         setUser(null);
     }
       
        //No token, no autenticado
        if (!token) return dispatch({ type:'notAuthenticated'});
     
             
 
     }
 
 
  useEffect(() => {
         async function asyncCall(){
             await checkToken();
         }
         asyncCall();
     },[signIn]);

   
   
    const removeError = () => {

     dispatch({type: 'removeError'});

    };

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            ...state,
            signUp,
            signIn,
            logOut,
            removeError,
            user:theUser,
            checkToken,
        }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```